# Getting rid of \r\ from an array imported from a .txt file

Tags: ruby

Input.txt :

```
foo
fooboo
boofoo
boo
```

---

main.rb :

```
foo = File.read("input.txt")

print Array(foo)

#=> ["foo\r\fooboo\r\boofoo\r\boo"]
```

This output is no good.  I want all my foo's and friends to be like this:

```
#=> ["foo", "fooboo", "boofoo", "boo"]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not use readlines?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do as below :

```
File.readlines('input.txt').map(&:strip)
# => ["foo", "fooboo", "boofoo", "boo"]
```

or

```
File.read('input.txt').split
# => ["foo", "fooboo", "boofoo", "boo"]
```